# Difference between asymptotic bound and running time

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms, analysis-of-algorithms

This question might be trivial but I really don't see the fine line here. I want to understand when I should say **asymptotic bound** of an algorithm vs **running time** of an algorithm. I understand that running time is said when you infer the time it takes for an algorithm to run for an input, such as *O(n)*. However, I don't know when I say asymptotic bound! I keep using them interchangeably but I feel there is a difference here. Kindly, can someone simplify these terms.

Thank you

Comment: $O(n)$ *is* an asymptotic bound for the runtime; it says that for sufficiently large $n$ the runtime is less than a constant (depending on a bunch of stuff, of course, but not $n$) times $n$.

Answer (score 0):

There is in fact an answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915842/difference-between-time-complexity-and-running-time.

The difference is that an asymptotic bound specifies the term that will be largest in runtime for hypothetical inputs that are of infinite size.

Let's take an example:

Suppose the runtime of your program is given by  $f(x)=1000x$.
For inputs that are small, this may take a long time. An input of size 1 will take 1000 seconds.

Suppose another program runs in $f(x)=x^2$.
  For this same input of **size 1**, the runtime will be **1 second**, so it seems like it's faster (which it is, for the given input). But what happens when input gets large?

The main point here is that, when talking about runtime, you have a given input size in mind, and runtime is a value, in seconds. When talking about asymptotic bounds, you're really talking about hypothetical performance for big input, which is when you *really* start caring about the performance of your algorithm.